# Same Queries returning different results in 2 different Oracle databases of same version

Tags: database, oracle11g

### Table Creation

```
CREATE TABLE demo
( 
  id number(10) NOT NULL,
  ct number(10) ,
  CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

### ROWS INSERTION

```
insert into demo(id,ct) values(1,4);

insert into demo(id,ct) values(2,2);

insert into demo(id,ct) values(3,3);

insert into demo(id,ct) values(4,2);

select * from demo

select q2.id,q2.ct from (
 select a1.id id,(SELECT sum(ct) from demo a2 
 where a2.id = a1.id) ct 
 from demo a1 ) q2 
group by q2.id
```

the above query is failing in one DB

> **ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   *Cause:
>
>   *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 14**

In another db it is returning the results with counts

DB Version : 11.2.0.4.0

Both databases are running on same version. The results of the below query is same in both DBs

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by should only by used with group functions (sum,count, avg etc).
Old databases engine used to accept group by as mean of order by , which is not the correct use.

The "group by" does not really have a meaning other than perhaps "order by"

Comment: The same query is executed on Oracle 11g but both DBs have different results. I wanted to know what is causing the queries show different behavior even though versions are same. Apart from product version , what entries should I check ?

Answer (score 0):

The query is wrong. You need to apply an aggregate function on q2.ct (e.g. sum(q2.ct)) or include it in the group by clause.

Comment: The query is working on other DB of same OS. Not sure if i need to check any patches installed in it.

Comment: Are you hunting bugs on oracle? If not, just fix the query and move on. The fixed query should work on any version. But if you are hunting bugs, I can’t help you as I don’t have those specific versions. =[